# How do I cluster and sequence data based on past observations?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, sequence, analytics, cluster-analysis

Let us suppose we receive sets of numbers on a periodic basis. These numbers are in a fixed interval, say one to one thousand. If I collect these numbers over a period of time, how do I

- find numbers that mostly appear together
- find what is the sequence these numbers mostly appear in.

For instance, `{790, 111, 432}`, `{123, 121}`, `{770, 123}` would result in

1. Groups:  `{790, 111, 432}` and `{123, 770, 123}`
2. Sequence: `{790, 111, 432, 770, 123, 121}`
   (or, `{770, 123, 121, 790, 111, 432}`)

And, `{790, 111, 432}`, `{123, 121}`, `{770, 123}`, `{770, 439, 98}`, `{111, 432, 190}` would result in

1. Groups:  `{790, 111, 432, 190}` and `{123, 770, 123, 439, 98}`
2. Sequence: `{790, 111, 432, 190, 770, 439, 98, 123, 121}`
   (or,  `{790, 111, 432, 190, 770, 123, 121, 439, 98}`
         `{123, 770, 123, 439, 98, 790, 111, 432, 190}`...)

The first one is possibly easy. I tried to create a distance matrix, and draw information from the distance matrix. The other idea I tried was to load into HDFS, and run a Mahout spectral clustering, with limited success. I feel have to use some clustering algorithm. Any help would be great.

The second is a more complicated problem, I think simple shuffling numbers around will not work, as there is the element of probability.

What is the right tool/algorithm to use for these two problems?

Comment: Sounds like either [frequent itemset mining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning) or [sequential pattern mining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_mining) to me.

Comment: As written, this question is entirely too broad for Stack Overflow. I would vote to close as too broad, but questions with open bounties can't be closed. As @larsmans pointed out, this is a [data mining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mining) problem, the solution to which is more involved than can be explained in a reasonably sized answer here. Go read up on data mining techniques, try some things, and if you have problems with your implementations, come back and ask *specific* questions.

Comment: @JimMischel, thanks for the input, but what is the specificity you expect? I did try graph theory (custom distance matrix based algorithm), and data mining (clustering algorithms through Mahout). As is, your comment does not help me understand your concern. If you could, like larsmans, let me know which part of data mining you are referring to, it would be of great help.

Comment: @larsmans, care to make it an answer?

Comment: @CMR, it's not a proper answer. It's just a suggestion to look for literature.

Comment: @larsmans, thank you. However, I found [these](http://www.philippe-fournier-viger.com/spmf/index.php?link=algorithms.php) based on your input. Especially [this picture](http://www.philippe-fournier-viger.com/spmf/map_algorithms_spmf_data_mining095.png) is very useful.

Comment: @CMR Feel free to answer your own question. In that chart, I recognize three names of algorithms and I'm only really familiar with one of them. I don't want to claim expertise in this area.

Answer (score 2):

Translate it to graph theory. Make a directed weighted graph, where the vertices are the numbers, every vertex is connected to every other vertex, and the weight on an A-->B edge is the number of times B follows A in a set. Now the problem is to find the highest weighted Hamiltonian path in this graph, which is basically an asymmetric [Travelling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem). Note that in TSP one usually finds the shortest path instead of the longest, but you can probably overcome this issue by negating all weights, although im not sure if negative weights will work for all algorithms.

I recommend using an [ant colony optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant_colony_optimization_algorithms) algorithm thats optimized for incremental data, but im no expert in graph theory.

Comment: I did try graph theoretic solutions. They help with the first part of the problem, not the second part.

Comment: @CMR what i described is a possible solution for the 2nd part of the problem, although there may be some more easily solvable abstractions of the problem.